Find $\sum_{n=1}^{2024} g_n\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}\right)$, where $g_n$ is defined recursively.

Problem Statement
Given a function $f(x)=x^2$, define $g_1(x)=f(x)$ and subsequently; $g_{n+1}(x)=\min_{t\in\Bbb R}(g_n(t)+f(x-t))$, where $n\in\Bbb N$. Find : $\sum_{n=1}^{2024}g_n\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}\right)$.

I am not interested in someone solving this for me. However, how would you generally approach such sums? I have tried things like trying to understand if $g_n(x)$ becomes repetitive, or if there is some pattern in the coefficients of $g_n(x)$ but nothing seems to work on this. Quite peculiar, the coefficients become exceedingly ugly and all of them are additive.
Any help, would be immensely appreciated.

I would approach it by finding out where the problem came from. If it came from a homework problem, I'd have some idea of what techniques might come in handy. If it came from a competition, I'd have some idea of how hard it might be.

@GerryMyerson; One of my modules for preparing for JEE advanced. Not a homework problem.

Is the answer $\frac{2024}{2025} $? $g_n(x) = \frac{x^2}n$. If you need a full solution do tell

@YashShrivastava Thankyou so much for your answer. Almost the second I read it I figured my silly mistake. Really dumb of me. I have been treating $g_n(t)$ as a function of x. Hence I was stuck. Now I can solve, and will update the answer formally. Yes, $\frac{2024}{2025}$ is the same answer I got.


Proof by induction of
$$\forall n\in\Bbb N\quad g_n(x)= \frac{x^2}n:$$
$$g_1(x)=x^2 ....(\text{base case})\\ 
$$
Assume,
$$
\begin{align*}
& g_n(x)= \frac{x^2}{n} \\ 
\implies &g_{n+1}(x)=\min_{t\in\Bbb R}\left(\frac{t^2}{n} + (x-t)^2\right) \\ 
&\because \text{Minima must be at}\; \frac d{dt}\left(\frac{t^2}{n} + (x-t)^2\right)=0 \\ 
\implies &\frac{2t}{n}- 2(x-t)=0 \\ 
\implies &t = \frac{nx}{n+1} \\ 
\implies &g_{n+1}(x)= \frac{nx^2}{(n+1)^2} + \frac{x^2}{(n+1)^2} \\ 
\implies &g_{n+1}(x)= \frac{x^2}{n+1} 
\end{align*}
$$
Then, $$\sum_{n=1}^{2024} g_n\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}\right)= \sum_{n=1}^{2024}\frac{1}{n(n+1)} \\ 
= \sum_{n=1}^{2024} \left(\frac1n- \frac{1}{n+1}\right) \\ 
= 1- \frac{1}{2025} = \frac{2024}{2025}.
$$

